# Pushing .NET WCF Application to Helion Stackato

Tags: wcf, cloud-foundry

When pushing .NET WCF application from VS 2013 to Helion Cloud Foundry, I get the error message "Could not find route StreamReceive.hpit.helion-cf.com"
The application list shows it's published and running, though.

Comment: When you say "it's running," do you mean you're looking at it through an IIS console or something?  Do you get the error when trying to push, or in trying to access?  In other words: did it even deploy, or is what's running out there just the IIS manager?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to step around the issue by manually adding map after publish\n
"stackato map myAppName myURL"